# How MSMQ will work?

Tags: c#, msmq

Hi anybody know how MSMQ work with c#? I got a small problem Actually i need to enter 10 urls in a queue and want to execute at 10 different time spans automatically.

Will it possible by using MSMQ with C# or is there any other technique is there?

Please suggest me how to do it

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you need to pass that data from one machine to another? why you want to store url's exactly in the queue?

Comment: MSMQ seems like overkill for 10 urls.

Comment: actually i want to execute n no.of tasks at a limited time intervals. So i'm searching for the technique. Can i achieve my goal through MSMQ?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a bulk downloader, I had a lot of success (5000+ sites per minute) with the [Concurrency and Coordination Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163556.aspx). CCR has fairly rugged scheduling capabilities, and helps to deal with the nasty threading issues that invariably arise from async IO. Jeff Richter kindly provides a set of wrappers for WebRequests.

It's hard to understand, but very rewarding when you do.

I wouldn't have considered MSMQ for this. Why do you?

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ is a product that is most of the time used to achieve reliable messaging between applications running in different machines. It can also be used between application running in the same machine but is less common, but the objective is the same. Some application puts a message in a queue and sometime later another application fetches the message.

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but probably you can manage using the Queue class and some threads and timers. Maybe it's overkill, but the open source schedule Quartz might also help.

Comment: thank you for your reply.. my problem is i want to store some urls in my queue with a different time intervals. Now i want to populate thouse urls with the specified time automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand your objective. My English skills are not the best :-). 
I will assume that you want to access those urls at different time intervals.
Using Quartz scheduler I would create different jobs with different timer intervals and assign to each job a specific an URL. The code for the jobs would do something with the URL.